# postgresql - pg_pathman - foreign keys

Tags: postgresql

Hello I'm Trying to partition a table... but this table has fk that refers to my table.

```
SELECT create_hash_partitions('crm.carga',  'id_carga', 100);

[Content]
ERRO:  foreign key "fk_carga_cliente_id_carga" references relation "carga"
CONTEXT:  função PL/pgSQL common_relation_checks(regclass,text) linha 31 em RAISE
comando SQL "SELECT public.common_relation_checks(parent_relid, attribute)"
função PL/pgSQL create_hash_partitions(regclass,text,integer,boolean,text[],text[]) linha 14 em PERFORM
```

Is possible to partition a table that has Foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant perform create_hash_partitions on 'crm.carga', because other table references it, look in the [code](https://github.com/postgrespro/postgrespro/blob/e7728cf470c695d5e83c85d4fb842375319b347c/contrib/pg_pathman/init.sql):

```
FOR v_rec IN (SELECT *
                  FROM pg_constraint WHERE confrelid = p_relation::regclass::oid)
    LOOP
        is_referenced := TRUE;
        RAISE WARNING 'foreign key ''%'' references relation ''%''',
                v_rec.conname, p_relation;
    END LOOP;
```

so the answer is: Yes, you can. But not with pg_pathman's function `create_hash_partitions`